# Result Only Work Environment

Tags: project-management

I would like to set up a ROWE for my dev team: Result Only Work Environment.

Basically, people work how they want, when they want, as long as the work gets done.
This environment has been a huge success for Best Buy: increasing productivity and reducing turnover.

Does anyone have any advice for making this work for a dev team?

Edit:

More details: I will be leading a team of 3 other fairly experienced developers. I plan on standardizing the basic processes, such as version control, bug tracking, code review, planning, testing, etc. "How they want to work" more refers to how they manage their time: i.e. scheduling meetings, pair programming.

Comment: I've heard about work environments like that.  The results sound great but the cynical side of me thinks that this will only work with the right type of developer.  I don't have any advice for you but I would sure love to hear how things went six months from now and what you learned.  Any plans for a blog or article on the experience?

Comment: How literally do you want to do this? ie do you want to give your devs freedom to choose their own version control and defect tracking tools? or just freedom to use the existing tools in whatever way they think best?

Comment: Good point. I am going to create a basic structure, and they will have freedom within this structure. The biggest freedom will be when and where they do the work. Freedom without structure = chaos. See above edit for more details.

Comment: TLiebe: I agree, this will not work for everyone. Keeping a blog about this is a good idea. Once I get management's approval on this plan :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have other departments in your org., consider managing their expectations as well. It will be difficult to convince them that their project is going to take longer (throw in all the technical jargon you can think of) than you thought when they notice your team is never around (in their eyes).

You'll still have to have realistic expectations in your planning. Are you really allowing for flex time when they have 10 hrs of work to do that is due in 10 hours? How are you going to handle trouble-shooting issues that get escalated to the dev team?

One developer could be consistently better than the rest/take less time, but the team may feel this person has a lighter workload. Get ready to crush some egos.

I guess pair-programming is out?

Comment: Pair programming isn't necessarily out. You would just need to find a partner who also valued the XP approach. There's nothing stopping someone from keeping a 9-5 schedule in the office, if they so desire. It's just that face time will not be mandated, because it doesn't work for a lot of people.

Comment: I think you will find that other parts of the organization will complain when their workers have to be there and your do not. And rightly so. You are providing a benefit they can't have and it could result in legal issues when the accounting clerk sues for the same rights. I can't imagine this idea would fly in any shop that is not pure development.

Comment: @HLGEM - Where do you draw the line? Is "NOT having to travel" a benefit that salespeople should have? What about being On Call? Does everyone show up when the server crashes at 3:00 AM? Put everyone on speaker phone, so we can all get cussed-out by an irrate customer.

Comment: a salesperson who doesn't travel will not get the job done, and be fired.

Comment: If you want to do this without consulting HR first, that's your option, but it will likely get you fired.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question is going to vary depending on the size and culture of the organization. Some would also argue that the process can matter, and you don't want your people taking any approach to achieve a result at the expense of something which they do not feel as as important.

Can you provide more info on the size of the organization and what working there is like today?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you hire the right people, you might find they work more than they WANT to admit X-).

Programming is more than a job, its a passion, and if you find the right person to fit your environment, performance measures go out the door, as the do it for the love of it.

Comment: Yes, Passion is the right word ;)

Comment: If you are in front of the PC programming after work.. its more than a job X-)

Answer (score 1):

WHEN they want will be easiear than HOW they want. I wouldn't give that much freedom to devs. IMHO, this would lead to a total mess of code.

There's very few very good developers out there today and those that are good enough should be made development leads and make the global decisions. Others should just follow the instructions or all hell can break loose.

Comment: Do you know 'why' this is happening in your organization? What is the root cause for this behavior?

Comment: It's just something that has to do with what kind of people you have around you, for this to work (giving everyone so much freedom that they can make their own decisions about real issues) you would need to have exceptionally dedicated people. But most people are not dedicated, they just search for 9-5 job and code "something" that works.

Comment: You're wasting a good programmer if their role as lead is to baby sit all day long.

Comment: that's not what I meant. Of course he would be doing his share of coding too. I just thought you can't put decisions in a hand of guys coming out college for their first year of real development job. I know for myself, I thought I was quite good 5 years ago but in reality I knew sh!t. It also depends on the programming language&tools used, put one college grad as C++ developer and let him unmonitored and you are destined for having memory leaks in your app all over the place. If we are talkin C# or Java this is of course less likely to happen but other pitfalls still exist.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define what the results they're meant to achieve are clearly and completely unambiguously so they understand what they can control (essentially how they work, the order they develop things in and so on) and what they can't (usually what they're expected to deliver - both in terms of actual product and supporting materials such as progress reports - and when it's all meant to be delivered).  You also need to let them know what resources they have - can they order high spec machines or order new software for instance or is that all decided?

I'd also ensure that one of their early deliverables was a schedule of completed milestones against which you could measure progress and agree with them what happens if they start missing milestones.

But I am slightly dubious about the idea that you're going to define version control, bug tracking and so on.  Surely these are things you should let them decide? After all they're part of the process.  Personally I'd state that they *must have* version control, centralised defect logging and so on but the mechanisms, tools and processes should be up to them.

It feels a little like you say you want to create a results only work environment but you don't quite trust them.  If you're saying what you're going to do is create a ROWE then you need to make sure it's just that otherwise you're really only doing half the process and those situations rarely deliver the benefits people are hoping for.

After all, either you trust them or you don't but if you can't trust them to work out how to do version control which is frankly second nature to developers, you probably shouldn't be trusting them with the schedule which is normally a far less straightforward matter.

Comment: Inviting other to be part of the process is good, but someone has to make the decisions. Choosing a bug tracking system for a developer can be tedious.

Comment: @jeff o - agreed but if you're saying that you're giving the developers authority to work however they want then the question should be "do you want to address this yourself or do you want me to?".  Surely the point of this approach is that the someone making the decision is the developers.  Otherwise it's just flexitime and working from home if they fancy - hardly revolutionary.

Comment: Traditional flex-time, is you have to work 40hrs/week whenever you feel like it. Results only is you have 'X' amount of work to do, and I don't care if you spend 4 or 80 hours. The problem with judging by Product/Result only, is if you don't give developers enough control and they feel they can't produce because they have not been give effective tools.

Comment: Interesting. Trust is essential, but in fact I don't trust them (I actually haven't met them yet). This is a new team. Trust will develop over time. A schedule will indeed be crucial. The tricky thing is that time estimation is a very very hard task for developers to get right (or anyone for that matter). So, I think the key is developing a history of estimation for each developer, so that they get better at making these estimates.

I don't think that setting up the bedrock processes is not trusting them. I view it more as getting these details out of the way so that they can get to work.

Comment: There are some excellent solutions out there. My preferred stack is

Git+Redmine+xUnit+Hudson+IM+eMail+Voicemail+Facetime

Answer (score 0):

Results oriented means that you must trust your developers to make the best decisions. Some people love this freedom. They cheer when they have the freedom to use a wrench as a hammer if it meant quicker results, rather than switching tools just to nail a picture on the wall.

But sometimes it could be damaging. Processes are designed for maximum productivity, efficiency, and effectiveness, with all kinds of safety measures. With the wrong subversion tool, a developer could easily slip and delete all history of all work done by the team, thus eliminating the magical "undo" feature.

In another case, most fresh grads (that I know) don't have the knowledge or capacity to make decisions on their own. They may not produce as fast as they would be able to with someone barking orders at him/her. One of the most distinguishable characteristics of a fresh grad is when he is stumped or doesn't know what's going on, he doesn't ask for help.

Your developers must have the right set of mind in order to achieve goals. Freedom is good, but monitor and make sure it's the correct way to go.

Comment: Good points all. I think fitting in to this environment depends more on the personality of the developer than their experience level. I've seen co-op students with a lot of drive and initiative, and senior people who are strictly 9-5.